# Node JS: Add "/" on end of all url if there is not

Tags: node.js, url, express

How can i add "/" on end of all url if there is not on Node JS / Express ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is check whether the string last character is "/", and if its not add it.

like this:

```
var addSlash = function( str ) {
    return str.substr(-1) !== "/" ? ( str + "/" ) : str
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = require('url');

function addSlash = function (str) {
   var u = url.parse(str);
   if (u.pathname.substr(-1) !== "/") {
      u.pathname += "/"; 
   }
   return url.format(u);
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain why this should work?

Answer (score 0):

`lastIndexOf` return the  last position where a slash is, and if it isn't at the end of the string, we add a slash to the url.

```
 function addSlash(url) {
    return url.lastIndexOf("/") == url.length - 1 ? url + "/" : url:
 }
```

No modules required.